Json serialize and deserialize protobuf generated types
I have some objects that are generated from protobuf and at some point these types need to be serialized and deserialized into JSON. The issue I have is we have a map field in the protobuf which is generated as a get only property
private readonly pbc::MapField<uint, global::ConnectionInfo> foundDevices_ = new pbc::MapField<uint, ConnectionInfo>();

public pbc::MapField<uint, ConnectionInfo> FoundDevices {
  get { return foundDevices_; }
}

Since this is get only the JSON serializer cannot deserialize this property. Ideally I wouldn't have to create a serialization model for this.
This protobuf type is within a parent type:
public class Summary
{
   ...

    public Dictionary<DateTime, Topology> Topologies{ get; set; }
    
    ...
}

and this Summary class is the object that gets serialized.
I have seen custom JSON Converters but I would have to apply this to the Topology Dictionary, and I would just make it so the serialization/deserialization just use the protobuf serialization for IMessage types. Though I not quite sure how to apply this converter only to the Topology type and not the Dictionary<DateTime, Topology> type.
